# Predicting Influence of Price on Sales with Limited Stock

Tags: regression, forecasting, econometrics

I'm trying to develop a model that predicts the volume of sales (either incremental for each day, or total at the end of a period) that factors in price, but I'm having some trouble working around some factors. The first is that stock is limited, so demand above a certain threshold is not realized in the data I have. This makes it hard for me to see the exact influence of price on during stock outs. In addition to that, as stock decreases, the desirability of the product is decreasing as well. This causes my most desirable products to lose steam as the end of the period approaches, because all of the best stock is gone.

Are there any potential methods I could use to help solve these data issues? Think of it like selling tickets to a concert or a sporting event if that helps. The two situations aren't entirely similar, but they're very close.